# Sirach: How does indulging in lust make you the laughingstock of your enemies?

Tags: sirach

Sexual acts are done in private, behind closed doors.

So how would a person's enemies be able to find out and then laugh at the person later when the person is committing sexual immoralities in private?

(I have a theory but first I want to hear others)

Sirach 18:30-31

> <sup>**30**</sup> Do not follow your base lusts but restrain your appetites. <sup>**30**</sup> If you allow your soul to take pleasure in base lusts, it will make you the laughingstock of your enemies.

Sirach 6:2-4

> <sup>**2**</sup> Do not fall into the grip of lust or you may be torn apart as by a bull <sup>**3**</sup> Your leaves will be devoured and your fruit destroyed, and you will be left like a withered tree. <sup>**4**</sup> Evil passion destroys those who have it, and makes them the laughingstock of their enemies.

Comment: Incidentally, here are remotely related verses that suggest public exposure of  sexual lustful acts:  (Proverbs 6:32-34)
 The one who commits adultery with a woman is lacking sense;
He who would destroy himself does it.
Wounds and disgrace he will find,
And his reproach will not be blotted out.
 For jealousy enrages a man,
And he will not spare in the day of vengeance.

Answer (score 1):

Those two quotations from Sirach agree with other Wisdom literature in the Hebrew scriptures. However, there seems to be an assumption here that both quotes refer *only* to sexual lusts. That could certainly be the case, and context may show that, but Wisdom literature never limits lust to sexual passion. Strangely, in this day and age, almost everybody seems to think that lust is all about inordinate sexual desires, and nothing else.

Well, Psalms 105:40-41 shows God satisfying the Israelites in the wilderness with quail and water. But in Psalm 106:13-15 it adds that:

> "They soon forgat his works; they waited not for his counsel: but
> instead lusted exceedingly in the wilderness, and tempted God in the
> desert. And he gave them their request; but sent leanness into their
> soul." A.V.

***Their lust on that occasion was for food*** they had enjoyed in Egypt, not the constant supply of manna from heaven. Another time when the nation lusted was while Moses was up the mountain for a very long time, and ***they longed for a molten image of a calf around which they could cavort and celebrate***, as did the Egyptians. That was also a form of lust.

**A lust is a great longing that over-rides sense and reason** and (when it is sexual) common decency; and this is why a person's enemies may discover their inordinate passion and laugh at them. The lust may be hidden at first, but because the person is being controlled by their feelings and desires, and not by reason (or wisdom), they end up doing things that expose their folly.

With sexual lust, there may be an end result of pregnancy (whether or not carried to full term). Or, perhaps, divorce. Or even murder committed by an enraged third party who discovers the betrayal.

Also, in this day and age, sexual lust is inflamed by the massive industry of pornography, with visual stimulus available to almost everybody at the click of a mouse. And sexual promiscuity is now no longer viewed as offensive in many parts of the world, so that there is blatant manifestation of the sexual desires that increasing numbers of people are giving in to. It is so blatant now that sexual lust is treated as entertainment. We are fast approaching a time when it will no longer be viewed as bad, or immoral, or undesirable. Such lusts are being actively promoted in many societies, so that we will soon find that those who resist sexual lusts, taking a stand against such things, will become the laughing-stock of those who indulge in it. How perverse will that be?

Comment: Incidentally, here are remotely related verses that suggest public exposure of  sexual lustful acts:  (Proverbs 6:32-34)
 The one who commits adultery with a woman is lacking sense;
He who would destroy himself does it.
Wounds and disgrace he will find,
And his reproach will not be blotted out.
 For jealousy enrages a man,
And he will not spare in the day of vengeance.

Answer (score 0):

Sirach presumed that lustful acts committed privately will be exposed during one's life on earth and thus subject the sinner to public ridicule. This follows the pattern of biblical teachings such as those in Psalms and Proverbs, where the righteous are  normally rewarded and the wicked punished in earthly life. (This is not present in other Wisdom Literature such as Job and Ecclesiastes, where the righteous suffer and the wicked may prosper).

In the New Testament we find a similar attitude to the quotes from Sirach in Luke 12:

> There is nothing concealed that will not be revealed, nor secret that
> will not be known. 3 Therefore whatever you have said in the darkness
> will be heard in the light, and what you have whispered behind closed
> doors will be proclaimed on the housetops.

In answer to the OP question: Sirach's moral theology involves what I would call  version of the idea of [Karma, minus the doctrine of reincarnation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma).

> The intent and actions of an individual (*cause*) influence the future of
> that individual (*effect*): Good intent and good deeds contribute to
> good karma and happier rebirths, while bad intent and bad deeds
> contribute to bad karma and bad rebirths.

For Sirach, evil acts done in private would eventually be brought to light in one's current life. Conversely, he said:

> "Whoever obeys me will not be put to shame,
> and those who serve me will never go astray.” 23 All this is the book of the covenant of the Most High God,
> the Law which Moses commanded us
> as a heritage for the community of Jacob (Sirach 24)

**Sirach taught a kind of modified *Instant Karma* doctrine, in which lustful acts would be brought to light while one is still alive, rather than in the afterlife or one's next incarnation.**

Comment: Incidentally, here are remotely related verses that suggest public exposure of  sexual lustful acts:  (Proverbs 6:32-34)
 The one who commits adultery with a woman is lacking sense;
He who would destroy himself does it.
Wounds and disgrace he will find,
And his reproach will not be blotted out.
 For jealousy enrages a man,
And he will not spare in the day of vengeance.

Comment: Crimes tend to follow you around for the rest of your life, mainly because your crimes/offenses/violations/sins may have greatly upset a lot of people who cannot and will not forget what you did.  This is even more true if you claim to be a Christian, that absolutely enrages people, the height of hypocrisy they will call it.  Whatever you did might have been done privately, but chances are it won't stay private.  God may forgive you, as He did David, but many will never forgive you, or King David either.  Not much you can do.